# Command substitution error via SSH with Gitlab CI

Tags: shell, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to execute shell thru SSH with gitlab-ci and I encounter errors.

Variables have these values :

```
DEV_SERVER=myserver.domain.com
CODE_APP=4A
CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG=pretorien-feature-ci
```

part of gitlab-ci.yml looks like that :

```
review_app:
    stage: review
    before_script:
        # SSH key configuration
        # ...
    script:
        - ssh dev@${DEV_SERVER} \
                "CONTAINER_PORT=$(docker port app_${CODE_APP}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} 80 | cut -d ':' -f2)" \
                "&& echo 'My container port : ${CONTAINER_PORT}' > result.txt"
```

Gitlab CI return this error `/usr/bin/bash: line 109: docker: command not found`

I tried to change the docker command with docker binary path (/usr/bin/docker) or $(which docker) but I have the same issue.

So, I decided to use a different approach :

```
review_app:
    stage: review
    before_script:
        # SSH key configuration
        # ...
    script:
        - ssh dev@${DEV_SERVER} \            
            "{ read CONTAINER_PORT _; } < <(docker port app_${CODE_APP}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} 80 | cut -d ':' -f2)" \
            "&& echo 'My container port : ${CONTAINER_PORT}' > result.txt"
```

But, in this case, the file result.txt is **empty** and the variable CONTAINER_PORT too.

In both cases I checked commands directly in a shell, the result was good and I can read the CONTAINER_PORT value in result.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did makes the `docker` command running in the gitlab CI runner, which probably does not know it. I assume you want to run the `docker` command on the ${DEV_SERVER}, so you need to properly escape or enclose the subcommand in apostrophes to make sure it does not expand too early. Something like this should do that:

```
    - ssh dev@${DEV_SERVER} \
            "CONTAINER_PORT=\$(docker port app_${CODE_APP}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} 80 | cut -d ':' -f2)" \
            "&& echo 'My container port : ${CONTAINER_PORT}' > result.txt"
```

My test:

```
$ ssh localhost "echo \$(echo \$SSH_CLIENT)"
```

correctly writes the SSH connction information, which is available only in the session, but not on the local session.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much ! It works :)
Finally, I also used a printf instead of the echo

```
- ssh dev@${DEV_SERVER} \
            "cd ${DEV_REVIEW_DIRECTORY}/${CODE_APP}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}/" \
            "&& CONTAINER_PORT=\$(docker port app_${CODE_APP}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} 80 | cut -d ':' -f2)" \
            "&& printf '<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.replace(\"http://%q:%q\");</script></head></html>' ${DEV_SERVER} \$CONTAINER_PORT > redirect.html"
```